# get variable from one page

Tags: php

I'am a newbie also my language maybe bad, and looking for solution for my learning php code
let say i have many page i.e. etc page1.php ... page1001.php each page maybe:
inside of page1.php:

```
$color = "red";
$pages = "two";
$theme = "ocean";
$lang = "eng";
$charset = "ISO-8859-1";
etc (more..)
```

inside of page2.php :

```
$color = "blue";
$pages = "two";
$theme = "ocean";
$lang = "it";
$charset = "UTF-8";
etc (more..)
```

now i need to put the variable of each pages to one page, n just put a simple code in each pages to setting them so next time easily to edit, note I using plain text (flat file)

anybody help me? i give appreciate and say thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use "include"

Comment: ok thakyou...
but how to do that? because the variable maybe different...
ok variable i put the to one page let say parameter.php :
<?
//page1.php
$color = "red";
$pages = "two";
$theme = "ocean";
$lang = "eng";
$charset = "ISO-8859-1";
etc (more..)

//inside of page2.php :
$color = "blue";
$pages = "two";
$theme = "ocean";
$lang = "it";
$charset = "UTF-8";
//etc (more..)
?>

but when i put
include "parameter.php"; 
in each page1.php ...page1001.php not always suitable, that possible using array? but how...?

Comment: Use a switch on which page to include.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use:

```
require('page1.php');
```

This will work similarly, but cause an error if the page cannot be located.

see: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry maybe i give wrong explained:

I mean all content in page1.php up to page1001.php above i will move to one page call it as parameter.php
so parameter.php become:

```
<? 
//the value of page1.php 
$color = "red"; 
$pages = "two"; 
$theme = "ocean"; 
$lang = "eng"; 
$charset = "ISO-8859-1"; 
etc (more..)

//the value of page2.php : 
$color = "blue"; 
$pages = "two"; 
$theme = "ocean"; 
$lang = "it"; 
$charset = "UTF-8"; 
//etc (more..) 

//the value of page3.php :
$bla-bla = "bla-bla";
?>
```

now how to call the value of page1.php also page2.php in parameter.php above? if i using include "parameter.php"; in each page (page1.php up to page1001.php) sometimes not suitable to each of page...

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your data, you could put your values for a certain page into an associative array such as this:

```
//Page1.php
$page1Information('color' => 'red', 'pages' => 'two', 'theme = 'ocean');

//Page2.php
$page2Information('color' => 'blue', 'pages' => 'five', 'theme = 'forest');
```

Then you can include all the pages in your parameter.php file, and call upon the data in any one file by going:

```
echo $page1Information['color']; 
//Prints out "red"
```

Comment: thank You...
it's look nice
<? //this file named page1.php
inlude_once "parameter.php";
print $page1Information[] ; //this possible to call all value page1.php from "parameter.php file?
?>